# Airflow EMR execute step from Sensor

Tags: python, emr, airflow

I made the following DAG in airflow where I am executing a set of EMRSteps to run my pipeline.

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2017, 07, 20, 10, 00),
    'email': ['airflow@airflow.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 5,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=2),
}

dag = DAG('dag_import_match_hourly',
      default_args=default_args,
      description='Fancy Description',
      schedule_interval=timedelta(hours=1),
      dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=2))

try:
    merge_s3_match_step = EmrAddStepsOperator(
        task_id='merge_s3_match_step',
        job_flow_id=cluster_id,
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        steps=create_step('Merge S3 Match'),
        dag=dag
    )

    mapreduce_step = EmrAddStepsOperator(
        task_id='mapreduce_match_step',
        job_flow_id=cluster_id,
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        steps=create_step('MapReduce Match Hourly'),
        dag=dag
    )

    merge_hdfs_step = EmrAddStepsOperator(
        task_id='merge_hdfs_step',
        job_flow_id=cluster_id,
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        steps=create_step('Merge HDFS Match Hourly'),
        dag=dag
    )

    ## Sensors
    check_merge_s3 = EmrStepSensor(
        task_id='watch_merge_s3',
        job_flow_id=cluster_id,
        step_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('merge_s3_match_step', key='return_value')[0] }}",
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        dag=dag
    )

    check_mapreduce = EmrStepSensor(
        task_id='watch_mapreduce',
        job_flow_id=cluster_id,
        step_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('mapreduce_match_step', key='return_value')[0] }}",
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        dag=dag
    )

    check_merge_hdfs = EmrStepSensor(
        task_id='watch_merge_hdfs',
        job_flow_id=cluster_id,
        step_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('merge_hdfs_step', key='return_value')[0] }}",
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        dag=dag
    )

    mapreduce_step.set_upstream(merge_s3_match_step)
    merge_s3_match_step.set_downstream(check_merge_s3)

    mapreduce_step.set_downstream(check_mapreduce)

    merge_hdfs_step.set_upstream(mapreduce_step)
    merge_hdfs_step.set_downstream(check_merge_hdfs)

except AirflowException as ae:
    print ae.message
```

The DAG works fine but **I would like to use the Sensors to make sure that I am going to execute the next step if and only if the EMR Job has been completed correctly**. I tried few things but none of them are working. The code above doesn't do the job properly. Does someone know how to use the EMRSensorStep to achieve my goal ?

Comment: Are those custom sensors you wrote? I'm in the process of setting up airflow and emr and need a way to check the status of the steps within the cluster.

Comment: No those are sensor that you can find in the ```contrib``` package - see here  [https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/sensors/emr_step_sensor.py](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/sensors/emr_step_sensor.py)

Comment: Thx ... i didn't realize there were additional ones in the `contrib` directory.

Comment: Using your example as my guide, I'm curious to learn if you were able to get this to work? My issue is, once the very first step completes and the sensor passes, the cluster immediately terminates. I'm not able to run the next step. Is there a specific flag I have to pass for multiple steps?

Comment: That's another problem. When you issue your step, you should set the flag to avoid the termination of your cluster. [Check this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/UsingEMR_TerminationProtection.html). An example of how you should issue a step, you can find in [https://pastebin.com/WGiGrFr2](https://pastebin.com/WGiGrFr2)

Comment: **@luckytaxi**, **@spaghettifunk**, i think what you are looking for is [`KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/APIReference/API_JobFlowInstancesConfig.html#EMR-Type-JobFlowInstancesConfig-KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps); [Termination-Protection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/UsingEMR_TerminationProtection.html) is a safety mechanism that prevents **accidental termination of cluster** (and therefore loss of data) due to *human-error / programming mistake*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your EmrStepSensor tasks need to set correct dependencies, for example, check_mapreduce, if you want to wait for check_mapreduce to complete, the next step should be `merge_hdfs_step.set_upstream(check_mapreduce)` or `check_mapreduce.set_downstream(merge_hdfs_step)`. So it would be TaskA>>SensorA>>TaskB>>SensorB>>TaskC>>SensorC, try to use this way to set up the dependencies